ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Add Privacy Manifest IOS Flutter

We noticed one or more issues with a recent submission for TestFlight
review for the following app: Although submission for TestFlight
review was successful, you may want to correct the following issues in
your next submission for TestFlight review. Once you've corrected the
issues, upload a new binary to App Store Connect. ITMS-91053: Missing
API declaration - Your app’s code in the “Runner” file references one
or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API
categories: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp. While no action
is required at this time, starting May 1, 2024, when you upload a new
app or app update, you must include a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes array
in your app’s privacy manifest to provide approved reasons for these
APIs used by your app’s code. For more details about this policy,
including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for
usage, visit:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.

I know the steps to create privacy manifest file. But how do I find the accepted reason codes that is related to my app. As you can see in the image below there are multiple reason codes.

